# Sharepoint 2010 see list of rss subscribers

Tags: 2010

Is there a way to see a list of the subscribers to an RSS feed of a blog site?

Answer (score 1):

Not OOTB. RSS feeds provide no tracking features, but with a little wit and digging, you can look at the web logs to get an accurate count of how many times your RSS feed has been visited.

You can also implement a code counter for the RSS Feed page...